# AWS Lambda function using Boto3 timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have solved my own question, but am posting it anyway in the hope of saving someone else a few hours!

I have a serverless project on AWS using Python to insert a record into a kinesis queue.  However when I use boto3.client('kinesis') or the put_record function it seems to hang until it times out, with no error messages or other information.  Below is the function:

```
import boto3

def put_record_kinesis(data, stream_name, partition_key):
    print "create kinesis begin"
    kinesis = boto3.client("kinesis")

    print "put record begin"
    response = kinesis.put_record(StreamName=stream_name, Data=data, PartitionKey=partition_key)
    print "put record complete"
    print response
```

The serverless.yml definition is a follows:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
        - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
        - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
        - "kinesis:*"
      Resource: "*"

  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-...
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-...
      - subnet-...
      - subnet-...

  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  memorySize: 128

functions:
  LambdaQueueFunction:
    handler: python_file.queue
    memorySize: 1024
    timeout: 100

  LambdaDequeueFunction:
    handler: python_file.dequeue

resources:
  Resources:
    KinesisQueue:
      Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
      Properties:
        Name: kinesis-queue
        ShardCount: 1
    ChronosQueueMap:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
      DependsOn:
        - "LambdaDequeueFunctionLambdaFunction"
        - "IamPolicyLambdaExecution"
      Properties:
        BatchSize: 1
        EventSourceArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - "KinesisQueue"
            - "Arn"
        FunctionName:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - "LambdaDequeueFunctionLambdaFunction"
            - "Arn"
        StartingPosition: "TRIM_HORIZON"
```

When I run the function I see the following in cloud watch logs:

```
10:53:02 | START RequestId: 027bb0cb-acb4-11e6-b20c-1b587b734943 Version: $LATEST
10:53:02 | put records begin
10:54:42 | END RequestId: 027bb0cb-acb4-11e6-b20c-1b587b734943
10:54:42 | REPORT RequestId: 027bb0cb-acb4-11e6-b20c-1b587b734943   Duration: 100002.99 ms  Billed Duration: 100000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 22 MB
10:54:42 | 2016-11-17T10:54:42.155Z 027bb0cb-acb4-11e6-b20c-1b587b734943 Task timed out after 100.00 seconds
```

It turns out that the solution was that the lambda function did not have access to the internet.  By default a lambda function not in a VPC has internet access, but a lambda function inside a VPC does not.

To fix this I created a new subnet, route table, elastic IP and nat gateway.  They were configured as follows:

- The nat gateway uses the elastic IP and points to any subnet with an internet gateway
- The Route table has a route for local traffic (*.*.0.0/16 | Local | Active) and a route for all other IP's to the nat gateway (0.0.0.0/0 | NAT ID | Active)
- The is set to use the new route table.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Good tutorial = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcRKdEP94jM

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was that the lambda function did not have access to the internet. By default a lambda function not in a VPC has internet access, but a lambda function inside a VPC does not.

To fix this I created a new subnet, route table, elastic IP and nat gateway. They were configured as follows:

- The NAT gateway uses the elastic IP and points to any subnet with an internet gateway
- The Route table has a route for local traffic (`..0.0/16 | Local | Active`) and a route for all other IP's to the NAT gateway (`0.0.0.0/0 | NAT ID | Active`)
- The is set to use the new route table.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: How were you able to debug this? The silent "timeout" message isn't sufficient for me to figure out anything :-(

Comment: I used logging to work out which line the problem was happening on, then read up on the AWS documentation where I was that it needed the internet access to be able to access the kinesis queue and that lambda functions are not by default assigned an IP address.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying that. So essentially some sleuthing is definitely required :-)

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7) is also very helpful

Comment: There is at least one [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-vpcconfig) that explains this.

Comment: This plagued me for 2 days. silent timeout, debugging boto3 just showed multiple https requests open, no errors. 
Thank you so much for this!

Comment: No problem @Ben Jacobson

Comment: I wish you all many health and luck! thanks!

Comment: This was my basic issue, but the resolution for me was removing it from the VPC entirely. It was not a necessary component for using boto3 in my use case.